# How to undo multitouch drawing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, undo, forward

Please help me to undo and forward my draw. I store all paths into an pathArray and now I want to undo and foward the path ( like app Notes (Apple) ).
 Please help me to solve this!

This is my PathArray class

```
//  PathArray.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PathArray : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint start;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint end;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor* color;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat pathWidth;
- (instancetype) initWithStartPoint: (CGPoint)start andEnd: (CGPoint)end andColor: (UIColor *) color andPathWidth: (CGFloat) pathWidth;
@end
```

This is my Draw class

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [strokecolor setStroke];
    for (int i=0; i<pathArray.count; i++  ) {
        CGContextRef contex = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineCap(contex, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextBeginPath(contex);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(contex, pathArray[i].start.x, pathArray[i].start.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(contex, pathArray[i].end.x, pathArray[i].end.y);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(contex, pathArray[i].color.CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(contex, pathArray[i].pathWidth);
        CGContextStrokePath(contex);
    }
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch type] == UITouchTypeStylus)
    {
        if(drawable){
            [self.delegate changeScrollViewInteraction:NO];
            UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
            lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [self.delegate changeScrollViewInteraction:YES];
        return;
    }
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch type] == UITouchTypeStylus) //pencil touch
    {
        if(drawable){
            CGPoint newpoint = [touch locationInView:self];
            PathArray *paths = [[PathArray alloc]initWithStartPoint:lastPoint andEnd:newpoint andColor:strokecolor andPathWidth:pathWidth];
            [pathArray addObject:paths];
            lastPoint = newpoint;
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
            NSLog(@"%@",pathArray[0]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
    [super touchesMoved: touches withEvent: event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    if ([touch type] == UITouchTypeStylus && drawable) //pencil touch
    {
        [pathEndPointArray addObject:tempEndPointArray];
    }

    if ([touch type] == UITouchTypeStylus && !drawable)
    {
        [self.delegate CacheLIView_showPopup_message:@"Already cupped!"];
    }
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

}
-(void)undo{
}
-(void)foward{
}
-(void)re_draw_after_rotate{ }
```

I need to create these function.

Comment: Please show us the effort you yourself put into trying to solve your problem. This can include but is not limited to actual code, the results of your own conducted research or potential approaches you have taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following (no code here):

- create a second array `pathUndoArray`
- Upon undo, remove the last entry from `pathArray` (if exists) and add it (at the end) to `pathUndoArray`, then redraw.
- Upon redo, remove the last entry from `pathUndoArray` (if exists) and add it (at the end) to `pathArray`, then redraw.
- Upon a new touch, you'll have to delete the `pathUndoArray`

You could also take a look at `NSUndoManager`.

Comment: Thank you so much!